# how to use 2 database connection in one page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

how to use 2 database connection in one page in php
This is my code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("",$conn);

$db = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("",$db);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Client_table WHERE Client_Id ='" . $_POST["clients"] . "'");
$id = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Client_table.Name, Client_table.Client_Id FROM Client_table, user WHERE user.username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' AND Client_table.Branch = user.area Order by Name ASC");
```

**My preoccupation is that $result must fetch data from two different database.!!**

What I mean Is that:

1. (Client_table belongs to $conn database) and
2. (user table belongs to $db database)

And both in fetch in one query.

**Is that possible?**

How?

Thank you very much in advance.

Hi Guys.
This is my 2 databases

1. DB name: Test1
2. DB name: Test2

   ---

Test1

Client_table: {cl_id, name, branch, address}

user_table: {user_id, username, password}

Test2

sites_table:{sit_id, name, location, a_id(FK from area_table), status}

area_table: {area_id, user, pass}

**Please note that these 2 DB different**

This my Query:  SELECT site_id, 
                       site_name, user_id, username 
                FROM sites, user_table
                WHERE a_id = user_id 
                        AND status = 1 OR status = 2;

**I need anyone help. i cant join 2 database in 1 simple query! Please help**

Thank you!

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Does it definitely have to be one query?

Comment: Why can't you run the query on one, store the results, then run the query on the other?

Comment: no GIb It doesn't has to be in one query But One in One page and single column of a table. hope you understand

Comment: Jonas, If it's simple for you, please demonstrate it and I will surely appreciate it. just for better understanding

Comment: Oh and yes, have you tried running that code? What happens?

Comment: Daniel, Is there a better way to use my coding in a such a way that cannot be extrmely vulnerable to sql injection attacks as you said??? please help!

Comment: Thanks Jonas, Yes This is a good running code. But my point is that I want to use $result now to fetch data from 2 different database. I hope you understand my point! thanks

Comment: @ElieMbuyamba Yes. I gave an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Add true to the second mysql_connect method

```
$db1 = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pw"); 
$db2 = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pw", true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $db1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $db2);
```

This is required if the parameters provided to `mysql_connect` are the same by making sure that the connection is not re-used.

You need then to specify which connection you're using when querying by adding it as an argument to the method:

```
mysql_query("SELECT Client_table.Name, Client_table.Client_Id FROM Client_table, user WHERE user.username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' AND Client_table.Branch = user.area Order by Name ASC", $db2);
```

**Note** that you should not be using `mysql_*` in the first place since it's deprecated.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you Jonas, That's is exactly what i needed. It's working. you save me much time. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view accessing the data from the database where the user tabel is, in the database where is the Client_table.

Comment: Is there a way to represent what you have said in a php script? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If both databases are on the same server, it is possible (while it's not really a good practice to do so). You must prepend the database's name to your table name in your query.

For example, say the "Client_table" is in the "client_database", and the "user" table is in the "user_database", your FROM clause would be `FROM client_database.Client_table as Client_table, user_database.user as user`

You could also do it in 2 queries, having 2 connections (say $conn_client and $conn_user). Get all the "Client_table.Branch" values that you need from $conn_client, and then make your SELECT on $conn_user with a "WHERE user.area IN(...)".

Answer (score 1):

Simply use database names in query ex:

`select * from database1.Client_table where somthing=thing
union all
select * from database2.Client_table where somthing12=otherthing`

Comment: perhaps 2 different servers

Answer (score 1):

**There's 2 ways:**

**One:**

With mysql_close

```
mysql_select_db("", $conn);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Client_table WHERE Client_Id ='" . $_POST["clients"] . "'");
$id = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$col1=$id['Col1'];
$col2= $id['Col2'];
$col3= $id['Col3'];
mysql_close($conn);

$db = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("",$db);
$sql2 = mysql_query("OTHER QUERY FOR DATABASE2.TABLE2");
$id2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$col2_1=$id['Col2_1'];
//and so on...
```

**or with**

```
mysql_query("SELECT database1.dbo.table1.Col1_1, database2.dbo.table2.col2_1 where xx =xx");
```

Comment: Hi Mostafa, I think you can be right with the 2 statement. so, what I need is something like this: "SELECT sites.site_name, 
sites.site_id
      FROM sites, user 
      WHERE user.username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' 
AND sites.srep_id = user.area 
Order by sites.site_name ASC"; I tried to run with most of the people post here but still not getting something. please help.

Comment: @ElieMbuyamba Hmm, How can I help you with.. I will need database structures for both and what you are trying to achieve and why it's not working.

Comment: yes @Mostafa Mohsen i have 2 database. please check the add-on info that i just post-in. thank you